# How to return different value for a static method which is invoked during the flow during unit testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, robolectric

I'm trying to write unit testing for the following snippet.

```
class ABC {
    int getMyValue(final Activity activity) {
        if(MyClass.getInstance(activity).getValue() == 1) return 10;
        else return 20;
    }

    void doSomething() {
    }
}
```

I've tried something like this to test the `doSomething` function.

```
mABC = new ABC();

public void test_doSomething() {
   doReturn(20).when(mABC).getMyValue();
   //validate
}
```

How can I test `getMyValue` similarly? I would like to assert when the value is 1 it's returning me 10 and in all other cases, it's returning me 20.

I'm doing this in my android application. Is there any existing framework that can help me do this?

EDIT:

`MyClass` looks something like this

```
public class MyClass {

   private static Context mContext;
   public static getInstance(Context context) {
     mContext = context;
     return new MyClass();
   }

   private MyClass() {}

   public void getDreamValue() {
     Settings.Secure.getInt(mContext.getContentResolver(), "dream_val", -1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the essentials of `MyClass`?

Comment: Oh sure it's just a secure setting helper class which interacts with `Settings.Secure` and uses its `getInt` api and returns the value to other classes..

Comment: Are you sure that you need static accessor, this seems a bit error prone solution to me? Also I think that this will not even compile since mContext is not static. Could constructor `public MyClass(Context context)` be enough? That would make privatizing default constructor also unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider modifying your `MyClass` as follows.

```
public class MyClass {

   private static Context mContext;

   // Create a private variable that holds the instance. 
   private Myclass instance;

   public static getInstance(Context context) {
     mContext = context;

     if (instance == null) 
         instance = new MyClass(); // Assign the instance here 

     return instance;
   }

   private MyClass() {}

   public void getDreamValue() {
     Settings.Secure.getInt(mContext.getContentResolver(), "dream_val", -1);
   }
}
```

Now, as you are using Robolectric, you can set the `instance` value to a mock as follows in your test class.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class) 
public class ABCTest {

    @Mock
    MyClass mockInstance; 

    @Mock
    Context mockContext; 

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // Set the mock instance for MyClass
        ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(MyClass.class, "instance", mockInstance);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWhen1() {
       doReturn(1).when(mockInstance).getDreamValue();
       Assert.assertEquals(10, new ABC().getMyValue());
    }

    @Test
    public void testWhenNot1() {
       doReturn(2).when(mockInstance).getDreamValue();
       Assert.assertEquals(20, new ABC().getMyValue());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        // Set the instance to null again to enable further tests to run 
        ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(MyClass.class, "instance", null);
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Note: It looks like you are trying to provide a singleton instance of `MyClass`. Hence, you really should not create a new instance of `MyClass` in the `getInstance` function. I avoided creating a new instance each time, using the `null` check in my code.

Comment: You are right ! My bad. I said singleton but went against it by creating new instance each time. Thanks for correcting it.